# Regex to trim text between tags

Tags: php, regex, spaces

I expected this to be a simple regex but I guess my head isn't screwed on this morning!

I'm taking the source code of a page and tidying it up with a bunch of other preg_replaces, so by the time we get to the regex below, the result is already a single line string with things like comments stripped out, etc.

All I'm looking to do now is trim the texts between > and < char's down to remove extra whitespace. I.e.

```
<p>    hello world   </p>
```

should become

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

I figured this would do the trick, but it seems to do nothing?

```
$data = trim(preg_replace('/>(\s*)([^\s]*?)(\s*)</', '>$2<', $data));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Don't do tidying up using regexes. Use [`HTMLTidy`](http://us3.php.net/tidy).

Comment: I'm not just tidying up - I'm removing the doctype, head, scripts, comments, etc. Is HTMLTidy faster?

Comment: @Ric, did you check my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the /e modifier in regex to use the trim() function while replacing.

```
$data = preg_replace('/>([^<]*)</e', '">" . trim("$1") . "<"', $data);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Lots of good answers here but this one is the simplest and slots in with my code nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ridiculous way to do it lol:

```
$str = "<p>    hello world   </p>";
$strArr = explode(" ", $str);
$strArr = array_filter($strArr);
var_dump(implode(" ",$strArr));
```

Use the power of arrays to remove the white spaces lol

Answer (score -1):

A regex could be:

```
>\s+(.*[^\s])\s+<
```

but don't use it, there are better ways to reach that goal (example: HTMLtidy)

Answer (score -1):

You may use this snippet of code.

```
$x = '<p>    hello world   </p>';
$foo = preg_replace('/>\s+/', '>', $x);  //first remove space after ">" symbol
$foo = htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+</', '<', $foo)); //now remove space before "<" symbol
echo $foo;
```